# equivalence checking with Z3

Tags: z3

i am still new with Z3, and have a question: is it possible to use Z3 to do equivalence checking?

if that is possible, could you give me one example of checking 2 formulas for equivalence?

thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There are many ones to accomplish that using Z3. The simplest one uses the procedure `prove` in the [Z3 Python API](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/tree/master/examples/python). For example, suppose we want to show that the formulas `x >= 1 and x == 2*y` and `x - 2*y == 0, x >= 2` are equivalent. We can do that using the following Python program (you can try it online at [rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/CbSAF)).

```py
x, y = Ints('x y')
F = And(x >= 1, x == 2*y)
G = And(2*y - x == 0, x >= 2)
prove(F == G)
```

We can also show that two formulas are equivalent modulo some side-condition.
For example, for bit-vectors (i.e., machine integers), `x / 2` is equivalent to `x >> 1` if `x >= 0`
(also available [online](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/m5d)).

```py
x = BitVec('x', 32)
prove(Implies(x >= 0, x / 2 == x >> 1))
```

Note that, `x / 2` is not equivalent to `x >> 1`. Z3 will produce a counterexample if we try to prove it.

```py
x = BitVec('x', 32)
prove(x / 2 == x >> 1)
>> counterexample
>> [x = 4294967295]
```

The [Z3 Python tutorial](https://github.com/ericpony/z3py-tutorial) contains a more complicate example: it shows that `x != 0 and x & (x - 1) == 0` is true if and only if `x` is a power of two.

In general, any satisfiability checker can be used to show that two formulas are equivalent. 
To show that two formulas `F` and `G` are equivalent using Z3, we show that `F != G` is unsatisfiable (i.e., there is no assignment/interpretation that will make `F` different from `G`). 
That is how the `prove` command is implemented in the Z3 Python API. Here is the script based on the Solver API:

```py
s = Solver()
s.add(Not(F == G))
r = s.check()
if r == unsat:
    print("proved")
else:
    print("counterexample")
    print(s.model())
```

Comment: @LeonardodeMoura The link to Rise4fun does not work. Did they remove their service?